# Creating a data table with dates as weeks and a column for number of entries

Tags: r, dataset, grouping

I am trying to make a new data sheet in R, with the dates grouped into week number within the month e.g. Week 1 June, Week 2 June, Week 3 June.... and then a new column summarising the number of entries within each. For example, my current data set is:

[image]

I am attempting to isolate all the entries that are 'Vigilent' which I have already done using `data2 <- data2 %>% filter(data2$Activity == "Vigilent")`, however I now need to create a new dataset grouping the entries into weeks of the month.

I have already grouped the data into weeks of the year using:

```
x <- date2week(data2$Date, week_start = "Sunday", floor_day = TRUE)

table(x)

x

2008-W24 2008-W25 2008-W26 

       1        3        4
```

But I would like it in the format 'Week 1 June, Week 2 June etc' along with the number of entries within each week in a separate column. Is this possible?

[Here is the output from dput()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tym2w.png)

```
structure(list(Date = c("14/06/2008", "18/06/2008", "19/06/2008", 
"20/06/2008", "23/06/2008", "25/06/2008", "26/06/2008", "27/06/2008", 
"28/06/2008"), Location = c("Park", "Park", "Grassland", "Grassland", 
"Grassland", "Grassland", "Grassland", "Forest", "Park"), Age = c("Adult M", 
"Adult F", "Adult F", "Adult F", "Adult M", "Adult M", "Adult M", 
"Adult M", "Adult F"), Activity = c("Vigilient", "Vigilient", 
"Vigilient", "Vigilient", "Vigilient", "Vigilient", "Vigilient", 
"Vigilient", "Foraging")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

[My desired output is as follows (count values are fictional)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfh0V.png):

e.g. I the other columns can be discounted, I just want to know how many Vigilent occurrences there were for a given week in July

Comment: Can you please post your data by pasting the output of `dput(data2)` into your question?

Comment: Sorry LMc do you mind clarifying? Would you like the data pasted as a visible image in the question above? Or do you want me to physically write 'dput(data2)' in my console in RStudio and paste the result? Sorry I am new to R!

Comment: That's okay! Yes the latter: please paste that command into your console. Then copy and paste the output into your question. It's an easier way for us to access your data to help.

Comment: Ok thank you! :) I have updated the question to show the dput() output

Comment: Please copy and paste the output not as a picture. Paste the output directly as it is into your question. We need to be able to copy and paste that output to recreate your data.

Comment: Ah sorry, done now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Activity == "Vigilient") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Date = dmy(Date),
                Month = month(Date, label = T, abbr = F),
                Month_Week = week(floor_date(Date, unit = "week", week_start = 7))- week(floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) + 1,
                Label = sprintf("Week %i %s", Month_Week, Month)) %>% 
  dplyr::count(Label, name = "Vigilence Count")
```

**Output**

```
        Label Vigilence Count
1 Week 2 June               1
2 Week 3 June               3
3 Week 4 June               4
```

---

1. Most of the date functions come from the `lubridate` library: `dmy`, `month`, `week`.
2. `Date` gets overwritten by this code. It becomes a date object. If this is not your desired behavior/you need to preserve the original `Date` column then you might want to rename it something else in the `mutate` function.

Comment: Thank you so much LMc!! Can I ask how you would then group them e.g. in this case to give 1 value in Week 1 June, 4 values in Week 2 June and 3 values in Week 3 June?

Comment: You're welcome! The answer to your question depends on the final structure you desire. For example, what would happen to the other values in the group to get to one row? If you could post your desired output in your question that would help.

Comment: Your R skills amaze me I have to say, I have spent days trying to work this out! I have updated the question to clarify what I wish the data to look like at the final output, I hope this helps but let me know if you want further explanation. Can I also ask how to make the labels correspond with the actual week in July as opposed to the data set? Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem, you will get there with practice and learning from other great people on stackoverflow. I've updated my answer to reflect the week number in absolute terms. You can simply use the `count` function to get your desired output.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, I really appreciate your help and encouragement! Can I ask a final question if you don't mind, I am wondering why I get this error message when copy and pasting your answer into my console?                                                    
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Yes, I am assuming your problem is that you have not created the dataframe `df`. I created it from the output of your `dput` post: `df <- structure(list(Date = c("14/06/2008"...`. In base R `df` is also a function. So that's likely what you're trying to pass to the `filter` function and getting an error.

Comment: You might want to adjust the code I posted to pass your dataframe object, which you have named `data2` in your question.

Comment: Great, it worked! :) may I ask one final question (sorry), is there a simple way to change it from week of the month to week of the year? I know this section needs to be changed: Month_Week = week(floor_date(Date, unit = "week", week_start = 7))- week(floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) + 1, but I'm struggling to see where... can I also ask if this code will work on other data sets if I alter what I wish to filter and the labels?

Comment: Week of the year is easiest. All you need to do is `week(Date)`. Yes, this will work on any dataset that has a date column so long as you can get that column to be a date object.